# Have objective collapse theories been ruled out by recent experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Have [objective collapse theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-collapse_theory) been ruled out by recent experiments, such as the entanglement of macroscopic objects? (vibrating drumheads)